# How to configure squid for anonymous users?

Tags: 7, caching

My intention is to use squid to cache  pages for anonymous users. Ideally, the cache should be limited to some query-heavy pages.

I have looked around but could not find any up-to-date guide about Drupal 7+squid 2.7 on the same server.

I could set up squid but it misses the cache and I have difficulty defining squid.conf for my purpose.

So appreciate your help.

Comment: Hope this [Increasing Drupals speed squid caching reverse proxy](http://2bits.com/articles/increasing-drupals-speed-squid-caching-reverse-proxy.html) will help you

Comment: @inizio, I tried that guide but unfortunately I still get X-Cache: MISS

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://groups.drupal.org/node/170544#comment-730349)?